# Badge tracker on profile wraps oddly

Tags: bug, profile-page, design

On my profile page, where I am currently tracking the [jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins) badge, it's basically impossible to see that the progress bars are associated with the badge.

[image: Screen shot: reputation box in Summary section of profile]

The wrapping is probably caused by my browser window size, but it's not particularly small; this is from a window of approximately 1000x680 pixels.

Just to spell this out, I would expect the "9/100 score" and "12/20 answers" progress bars to be grouped with the "Next tag badge" information, perhaps by aligning them to the right in the reputation box just like the tag itself.

This is on a Mac running the Brave browser (basically Chrome minus selling the rights to your firstborn to Google).

Comment: (I know, people born after 1980 are unaware that you can run multiple applications in separate windows and look at them at the same time.)

Comment: Also, it's not like I ever expect to earn the [tag:jenkins] badge. I should probably switch to tracking a realistic one.

Comment: Odder still, it is correct on Meta. (Says this user born after 1980 who is running about a dozen different applications, each in their own window.)

Comment: @CodyGray Do you mean https://meta.stackexchange.com/? I don't see a badge tracker there at all (probably because I don't have enough rep?) but it's broken for me here on MSO.

Comment: @tripleee [Here is what my badge tracker looks like on Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed82R.png)

Comment: I meant MSO, where it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP4Gz.png) for me, on Brave. Now that I check, it also looks correct on SO proper. But now I see that it's a viewport-width wrapping problem. So, still a bug. Looks like `flex` might not be a panacea after all!

Comment: Funny how generally, the supposedly "responsive" design is markedly a degradation over the plain non-responsive one where it was supposed to help, at least until the devs make further tweaks, presumably adding more code and thus occasionally also more bugs.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the same portion of my profile here on meta, same browser window as before. https://i.stack.imgur.com/etrmcm.png

Comment: This started happening after the profile-page was made responsive. There are several variations to the misplacement depending if the rep graph is showing (it doesn't [below a certain narrowness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372868)) or on the metas), etc... But there are even stranger displays that can happen, [for example this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372806).